# Como detectar si un dispositivo ya había entrado anteriormente a mi app web? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

Buen día, estoy creando una aplicación web, pero necesito restringirla para que únicamente se pueda acceder a ella por 3 dispositivos diferentes (no es necesario que los 3 se conecten al mismo tiempo), por ejemplo: si un celular y dos computadoras accedieron a la aplicación, la app los detecte y ya no sea posible acceder desde otro dispositivo que no sea uno de esos.

Comment: Al hacer login, puedes generar un hash para ese dispositivo y guardarlo en una cookie. Lo registras en la BD, y en cada login, sumas el total de hash registrados, en el logout, borras la cookie y eliminas el registro.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.